# Why I can't unset my POST variable after showing it?

Tags: php

I am processing my form in one file. While showing the result I'm trying to unset it, but it is not working.

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND !empty($_POST['nvalue'])) {
        echo $_POST['nvalue'] . '<br>';
        unset($_POST['nvalue']);
    }
    else {
        echo "22222";
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <span style="font-size: 1.7em;">Randomizer</span><br>
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">How much values</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="nvalue" name="nvalue" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `unset($_POST)`. Right now you are attempting to unset `nvalue` in `$_POST`

Comment: Not working with $_POST

Comment: How are you concluding that the `unset` is not working?

Comment: While refreshing the page, I can still see the value from form

Comment: @M3ren check the answer now .Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unset is working. But in your code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND !empty($_POST['nvalue'])) { // in here you are checking is the variable is set or not

    echo $_POST['nvalue'] . '<br>'; // Now here this will echo the value

    unset($_POST['nvalue']); // In here you will unset the value **Please note unset is working in here**
}
else{
    echo "22222";
}
?>
```

But the problem is that your function almost executed and when someone leave text area as empty and submit the form then

`(isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND !empty($_POST['nvalue']))`
 this will be `false` and it will execute the `else` pharse.

**So that your `unset()` is working**

Just think if you use `method="GET"` then if some one enter 55 as the value your `url` will be like this

> `.../?nvalue=55`

So you are refreshing this `url` again and again. But this line

`(isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND !empty($_POST['nvalue']))` return `true`

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND !empty($_POST['nvalue'])) {
    echo $_POST['nvalue'] . '<br>';
    unset($_POST['nvalue']);

}
if (!isset($_POST['nvalue']) AND empty($_POST['nvalue'])) {
  echo "22222";
}

?>
```

If user input is **55**, then the output will be

> 55
>   22222  **//because your unset is working**

But I can't understand what are you trying to do something like this.

Comment: if anyone could can anyone please explain why is this answer got a -1 . Because I feel that this answer is right. If anyone could please explain if there is anything I missed. Thanks

Comment: Follow-up questions belong in comments to the question - this is not a forum.